# wordpress ajax is not working for dropdown selection

Tags: functions, ajax, javascript

Here is my dropdown selection which is getting from database.

```
    <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <label class="control-label col-sm-5">Project Choice 
                                        <span>*</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7">                                            
                                        <select class="form-control" id="category" name="project_choice" required>
                                            <?php
                                            $the_query = array(
                                                'orderby' => 'name',
                                                'order' => 'ASC',
                                                'parent' => 0
                                            );
                                            $categories = get_categories($the_query);
                                            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                                                ?>                                        
                                                <option value="<?php echo $category->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></option>
                                                <?php
                                            }
                                            ?>  
                                        </select>                                          
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

here is my result section which is associated with above category section.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <label class="control-label col-sm-5">Program 
                                        <span>*</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7" id="results">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Here is my enqueue script for forntend user.

```
function my_enqueue() {
wp_enqueue_script('ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
wp_localize_script('ajax-script', 'main', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
```

}

This is my main.js file script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#category').change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "html",
        data: {
            'action': 'get_program_by_category', // this is name of your function that gets trigger
            'datas': category // valuse you want to pass
        },
        success: function (data) {
            debug(data); // result that return from function
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Please [`edit`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/243959/edit) your question an elaborate on your question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue I see is the ajax url is incorrect. Your `wp_localize_script()` has the handle name 'main', not 'ajax_object'.

```
url: main.ajaxurl
```

Also, where is the callback code to handle the `get_program_by_category` ajax action? You're missing two actions.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
```

See the WordPress Codex to learn more about using the [AJAX API](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

**Update #1**

Try using this to debug. You should get a popup telling you either "Success" or "Failed". Also, the data will be logged to the brower console.

```
$.ajax( {
  url: main.ajaxurl,
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: "html",
  data: {
    'action': 'get_program_by_category', 
    'datas': category 
  }
} ).done( function (r) {
    console.log(r);
    if ( r.success ) {
      alert( 'Success!' );
    } else {
      alert( 'Failed!' );
    }
} );
```

Comment: now i have done given process but still not returning anything even console also.

Comment: still not working.i have added this function in function.php is it right add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
function my_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
    wp_localize_script('ajax-script', 'main', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue');

Comment: @UmeshShrestha I've updated my answer so please try that code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first localise the script & then you can use enqueue.

```
wp_localize_script('ajax-script', 'main', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
wp_enqueue_script('ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
```

Also in `url` of your ajax , it should be `url: main.ajaxurl` and not `url: ajax_object.ajaxurl`